# No FileSystem for scheme: webhdfs

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, webhdfs

I'm building a client which pushes some data into my HDFS. Because the HDFS is inside a cluster behind a firewall I use HttpFS as a proxy to access it. The client exits with an `IOException` when I try to read/write to the HDFS. The message is `No FileSystem for scheme: webhdfs`. The code is very simple

```
String hdfsURI = "webhdfs://myhttpfshost:14000/";
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(new URI(hdfsURI), configuration);
```

It crashes in the last line. I'm building with Maven 3.0.4 and added the Hadoop-Client dependency 2.2.0 to my project. Accessing via `curl` on the command line works fine.

Any ideas why this could be failing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17265002/hadoop-no-filesystem-for-scheme-file) question on SO I had to add the following code prior doing any FS activities:

```
configuration.set("fs.webhdfs.impl", org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem.class.getName());
```

I don't know why, but there seems to be something wrong with the Maven build process... for now it works.