# What is version of hadoop supported by cassandra 2.0

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, cassandra-2.0

I have written a job in hadoop 2.2.0, that reads a input file and bulks load the data in cassandra 2.0

However i got the error (its because of difference in distribution of hadoop used in compilation & execution)

```
[root@hadoopslave ~]# hadoop jar ultra-bulkloader-hadoop.jar
14/07/10 01:08:01 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /10.211.212.157:8040
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected
    at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.BulkOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(BulkOutputFormat.java:35)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.checkSpecs(JobSubmitter.java:456)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:342)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1268)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1265)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1265)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1286)
    at com.home.task.hadoop.bulkloader.BulkLoaderDriver.run(BulkLoaderDriver.java:38)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at com.home.task.hadoop.bulkloader.BulkLoaderDriver.main(BulkLoaderDriver.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
```

What is the version of hadoop supported by cassandra 2.0

Comment: It's compatibility issue with hadoop 1 / 2 jars. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22630323/hadoop-java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror-found-interface-org-apache-hadoo 
and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21873050/pig-found-interface-org-apache-hadoop-mapreduce-jobcontext-but-class-was-expe

Comment: Yeah i had searched that, but my question is what is the version of hadoop supported by cassandra 2.0.
Also someone has marked it as duplicate. But this isn't and is related to query over cassandra's hadoop version

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nosql-databases/Y-9amAdZk1s

Comment: Hope someone merges https://github.com/VerticalSearchWorks/cassandra/tree/Cassandra2-CDH4 to main cassandra release

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix is available on cassandra 2.0.6

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5201

Answer (score 0):

I fixed similar issue, updating api from **cassandra 1.1.1** to **cassandra 2.0.7**, as I was running **cassandra 2.0.7**

```
      <properties>                                                                                    
              <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>                      
~             <cassandra.version>2.0.7</cassandra.version>                                            
      </properties>  

          <dependency>                                                                                   
              <groupId>org.apache.cassandra</groupId>                                                    
              <artifactId>cassandra-all</artifactId>                                                     
              <version>${cassandra.version}</version>                                                    
              <exclusions>                                                                               
                  <exclusion>                                                                            
                      <artifactId>libthrift</artifactId>                                                 
                      <groupId>org.apache.thrift</groupId>                                               
                  </exclusion>                                                                           
              </exclusions>                                                                              
          </dependency>                                                                                  
          <dependency>                                                                                   
              <groupId>org.apache.cassandra</groupId>                                                    
              <artifactId>cassandra-thrift</artifactId>                                                                                               
              <version>${cassandra.version}</version>                                                    
              <exclusions>                                                                               
                  <exclusion>                                                                            
                      <artifactId>libthrift</artifactId>                                                 
                      <groupId>org.apache.thrift</groupId>                                               
                  </exclusion>                                                                           
              </exclusions>                                                                              
          </dependency>
```