# running hadoop wordCount example with groovy

Tags: java, hadoop, groovy, hadoop2, hadoop-streaming

I was trying to run the wordCount example with groovy using [this](http://tthevis.github.io/groovy-hadoop/) but encounter an error

```
Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected
```

found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22630323/hadoop-java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror-found-interface-org-apache-hadoo) for above error but could not locate pom.xml file in my setup.

Then I came across [this](http://hadoop-course.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/JHU605.788/HadoopSamples/src/main/java/mr/wordcount/groovy/CountGroovyJob.groovy). How do we run this in hadoop. Is it by making a jar file and run similarly as the java example?(which ran fine)

What is the difference between running a groovy example using `groovy-hadoop` and by using [this](http://hadoop-course.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/JHU605.788/HadoopSamples/src/main/java/mr/wordcount/groovy/CountGroovyJob.groovy) file (not sure how to run this) and `hadoop-streaming`? why would we use one method over others.

I've installed hadoop 2.7.1 on mac 10.10.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to run  [this](http://hadoop-course.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/JHU605.788/HadoopSamples/src/main/java/mr/wordcount/groovy/CountGroovyJob.groovy) groovy file with hadoop  2.7.1 
The procedure I followed is

1. Install gradle
2. Generate jar file using gradle. I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36039514/groovy-hadoop-jar-with-gradle-package-not-exist-error) question which helped me build dependencies in gradle
3. Run with hadoop as usual as we run a java jar file using this command from the folder where jar is located.

   `hadoop jar buildSrc-1.0.jar in1 out4`

where `in1` is input file and `out4` is the output folder in hdfs

**EDIT-** As the above link is broken , I am pasting the groovy file here.

```
import StartsWithCountMapper
import StartsWithCountReducer
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner


class CountGroovyJob extends Configured implements Tool {
    @Override
    int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Job job = Job.getInstance(getConf(), "StartsWithCount")
        job.setJarByClass(getClass())

        // configure output and input source
        TextInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]))
        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat)

        // configure mapper and reducer
        job.setMapperClass(StartsWithCountMapper)
        job.setCombinerClass(StartsWithCountReducer)
        job.setReducerClass(StartsWithCountReducer)

        // configure output
        TextOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]))
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat)
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text)
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable)

        return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1
    }

    static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.exit(ToolRunner.run(new CountGroovyJob(), args))
    }

    class GroovyMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
        private final static IntWritable countOne = new IntWritable(1);
        private final Text reusableText = new Text();

        @Override
        protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Mapper.Context context) {
            value.toString().tokenize().each {
                reusableText.set(it)
                context.write(reusableText,countOne)
            }
        }
    }

    class GroovyReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable>{
        private IntWritable outValue = new IntWritable();
        @Override
        protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Reducer.Context context) {
            outValue.set(values.collect({it.value}).sum())
            context.write(key, outValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The library you are using, groovy-hadoop, says it supports Hadoop `0.20.2`. It's really old.

But the `CountGroovyJob.groovy` code you are trying to run looks like it's supposed to run on versions `2.x.x` of Hadoop. 
I can see this because in the imports you see packages such as `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper`, whereas before version 2, it was called `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper`.

The most voted answer in the SO question you linked is probably the answer you needed. You have an incompatibility problem. The groovy-hadoop library can't work with your Hadoop 2.7.1.

Comment: Thanks. Most voted answer asked us to update pom.xml, but where is it. I look at `/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.1/libexec/etc/hadoop`. Also looked in `/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.1/libexec/sbin`, but could not locate. Also, Any idea how to run the groovy file I linked to?

Comment: The pom.xml is the Maven configuration file to BUILD the library. It's how the author of this old library used to build the jars which are available on that website. Unfortunately it looks like he didn't share his source code (I can't find it anyways), so you can't modify that pom.xml and rebuild/fix it.