# groovy hadoop jar with gradle - package not exist error

Tags: java, hadoop, gradle, dependencies

I was trying to create a groovy jar with Gradle 2.12 . The groovy file has import statements as below and I put this file in `src/main/groovy`

The first two import are java files, which inturn have `org.apache.hadoop` imports statements. I put these two files in `src/main/java`

```
import StartsWithCountMapper
import StartsWithCountReducer
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner
```

And below is my build.gradle file (using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9749032/create-a-groovy-executable-jar-with-gradle))

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'application'
version = '1.0'
mainClassName='CountGroovyJob'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.0.0'
    compile 'org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:2.7.1'

}

task Createjar(type: Jar,dependsOn:[':compileJava',':compileGroovy']) {
    from files(sourceSets.main.output.classesDir)
    from configurations.runtime.asFileTree.files.collect { zipTree(it) }

    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': mainClassName
    }
}
```

I have tried to compile with below also, by putting them in dependencies

```
     compile 'org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.0.1'
    compile 'org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-core:1.2.1'
    compile 'org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-hdfs:2.7.1'
```

but I keep on receiving this error:

```
/Users/../../../gradle/buildSrc/src/main/java/StartsWithCountMapper.java:5: error: package org.apache.hadoop.io does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
                           ^
/Users/../../../gradle/buildSrc/src/main/java/StartsWithCountMapper.java:6: error: package org.apache.hadoop.io does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
                           ^
/Users/../../../gradle/buildSrc/src/main/java/StartsWithCountMapper.java:7: error: package org.apache.hadoop.io does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
```

how can I compile and create a jar with all those import statements in groovy and java files?

**EDIT**
to include buildscrip{}

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'application'
version = '1.0'
mainClassName='CountGroovyJob'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.0.0'
    compile 'org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:2.7.1'

}

task Createjar(type: Jar,dependsOn:[':compileJava',':compileGroovy']) {
    from files(sourceSets.main.output.classesDir)
    from configurations.runtime.asFileTree.files.collect { zipTree(it) }

    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': mainClassName
    }
}

buildscript{
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.0.0'
        compile 'org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:2.7.1'
    }
}
```

folder structure :

```
 grad-proj
 |
 +-- build.gradle
 |    
 +-- src
    |  
    +-- main
       |
       +-- groovy
       |
       +-- java
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The import statements are in code that is in `buildSrc` and not `main`, which means that the dependencies are required by the buildscript dependencies section.

Instead you are applying dependencies to the general dependencies section which applies to source which lives in the `main` directory.

Add to your build.gradle:

```
buildscript{
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.0.0'
        compile 'org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:2.7.1'
    }
}
```

Comment: I am confused now, according to [this](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html#sec:build_sources) , section 41.4 , "put your build source code in this directory and stick to the layout convention for a Java/Groovy project " and just above this statement , theres no `buildscript{}` .mentioned (fig 41.1)

Comment: where is the `build.gradle` you quoted located? If you're doing things as per section 41.4, build.gradle needs to be in the buildSrc folder.

Comment: oh ok, my build.gradle is outside `buildsrc` folder.  I have these `gradle/buildSrc/src/main/groovy` and `gradle/buildSrc/src/main/java`. i'll let you know the results.

Comment: after adding `buildscript{}` code and changing build.gradle location to inside `buildScrc` folder,  got this error  `Could not find method compile() for arguments [org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.0.0] on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@5a8cbffe` .

Comment: Update: Actually I tried without buildscript{} code and just by putting build.gradle inside buildSrc and it did compile a lot of dependencies but it now gives me this `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce does not exist`.

Comment: You only need to do one of the two. use `buildscript{}` OR move build.gradle into buildSrc. As for mapreduce, looks like you're missing more compile dependencies.

Comment: ok, I added `'org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-core:1.2.1'`and it built. But I still can't build using `buildscript{}` . I copied the original `src` folder and build.gradle into a new folder (not buildSrc) , added `buildscript{}` code and tried to run from there but get the same error `Could not find method compile()`. Edited above to include modified build.gradle. Just trying to understand the difference.

Comment: can you show your folder structure as an ascii diagram?

Comment: But now, your code files aren't in buildSrc, which means you do not require `buildScript{}`

Comment: but when the code files were in buildSrc even then I didn't require any `buildscript{}` , my Update above. Do you mean to say we use `buildscript{}` when the code is in `buildSrc` but build.gradle is outside `buildSrc` ? One other question I had is that the dependencies are source code related and not for the build script itself, so why do we need `buildScript` at all? I am confused more now.

Comment: Yes, exactly. you only use buildscript{} when source is in buildSrc but build.gradle is outside. Maybe I should rewrite my answer to clarify this - will get to it in a bit. Any sourcecode that is inside buildSrc is treated as part of (or an add-on to) the build script, it isn't part of the "source" that the build script builds.

Comment: Btw, you should upvote answers you find useful. http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I was going to upvote and accept. Its just that, it was taking time for me to produce results using `buildScrit{}` (during the day I don't have access to my code) . Sorry, didn't mean to make you feel that way.