# A problem occurred evaluating settings 'android'. gradle.groovy does not exist

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I am getting following error message while running the command :

`react-native run-android`

> A problem occurred evaluating settings 'android'.
>
> Could not read script 'E:\sharjeel\reactn\Ecomm1\node_modules\react-native-unimodules\gradle.groovy' as it does not exist.

Comment: Go to the project's root folder and run npm install and it will generate the necessary files, including react.gradle

Comment: already done that, the problem persists

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36039514/groovy-hadoop-jar-with-gradle-package-not-exist-error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved by running

> npm install react-native-unimodules

at the root of the project

Comment: does not work if using yarn workspace monorepo