# Failed to load com.databricks.spark.csv while running with spark-submit

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I am trying to run my code with spark-submit with the below command.

```
spark-submit --class "SampleApp" --master local[2] target/scala-2.11/sample-project_2.11-1.0.jar
```

### And my sbt file is having below dependencies:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.4.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "1.5.2"

libraryDependencies += "com.databricks" % "spark-csv_2.11" % "1.2.0"
```

### My code :

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer 
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext

object SampleApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Sample App").setMaster("local[2]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc) 

    import sqlContext._ 
    import sqlContext.implicits._

    val df = sqlContext.load("com.databricks.spark.csv", Map("path" -> "/root/input/Account.csv", "header" -> "true"))

    val column_names = df.columns
    val row_count = df.count
    val column_count = column_names.length

    var pKeys = ArrayBuffer[String]()

    for ( i <- column_names){
         if (row_count == df.groupBy(i).count.count){
             pKeys += df.groupBy(i).count.columns(0)
         }
     }

    pKeys.foreach(print)
  }
}
```

### The error:

```
16/03/11 04:47:37 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load class for data source: com.databricks.spark.csv
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.ResolvedDataSource$.lookupDataSource(ddl.scala:220)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ddl.scala:233)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.load(SQLContext.scala:1253)
```

My Spark Version is 1.4.1 and Scala is 2.11.7

(I am following this link: http://www.nodalpoint.com/development-and-deployment-of-spark-applications-with-scala-eclipse-and-sbt-part-1-installation-configuration/)

I have tried below versions of spark csv

```
spark-csv_2.10 1.2.0
1.4.0 
1.3.1
1.3.0
1.2.0
1.1.0
1.0.3
1.0.2
1.0.1
1.0.0
```

etc.

Please help!

Comment: For starters your dependencies are messed up. SQL version should match core version.

Comment: @zero323 thank you, I will try matching them. But its not able to load the data :(

Comment: Next `SQLContext.load` method has been deprecated in 1.4.1. Use `DataFrameReader` methods instead.

Comment: Also, have you build Spark with Scala 2.11?

Comment: i used below command : build/mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.4 -Dhadoop.version=2.4.0 -Dscala-2.11 -DskipTests clean package
Now changed SQL version to 1.4.1, will work on DataFrameReader
Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: There are examples how to use reader in `spark-csv` README. Finally add `--packages com.databricks:spark-csv_...` to the `spark-submit` replacing `...` with Scala version and package version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are running the job in local mode, add external jar path using `--jar` option

> spark-submit --class "SampleApp" --master local[2] **--jar file:[path-of-spark-csv_2.11.jar],file:[path-of-other-dependency-jar]** target/scala-2.11/sample-project_2.11-1.0.jar

e.g.

```
spark-submit --jars file:/root/Downloads/jars/spark-csv_2.10-1.0.3.jar,file:/root/Downloads/jars/com‌​mons-csv-1.2.jar,file:/root/Downloads/jars/spark-sql_2.11-1.4.1.jar --class "SampleApp" --master local[2] target/scala-2.11/my-proj_2.11-1.0.jar
```

**Another thing** you can do is create a fat jar. In SBT you can try this [proper-way-to-make-a-spark-fat-jar-using-sbt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30414782/proper-way-to-make-a-spark-fat-jar-using-sbt) and in Maven refer [create-a-fat-jar-file-maven-assembly-plugin](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/create-a-fat-jar-file-maven-assembly-plugin/)

**Note:** Mark scope of Spark's (i.e. spark-core, spark-streaming, spark-sql etc) jar as **provided** otherwise fat jar will become too fat to deploy.

Comment: this worked, thanks a lot, but now I am getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat\

Comment: The command used is : spark-submit --class "SampleApp" --master local[2] --jars file:/root/Downloads/jars/spark-csv_2.10-1.0.3.jar,/root/Downloads/jars/commons.csv-1.2.jar,/root/Downloads/jars/spark-sql_2.11-1.4.1.jar target/scala-2.11/my-proj_2.11-1.0.jar

Comment: `spark-csv_2.11.jar` depends on `org.apache.commons » commons-csv` so you also have to add `commons-csv.jar` to. To solve this dependency issue I have updated the answer.

Comment: Try updated command : `spark-submit --class "SampleApp" --master local[2] --jars file://root/Downloads/jars/spark-csv_2.10-1.0.3.jar,file://root/Downloads/jars/commons.‌​csv-1.2.jar,file://root/Downloads/jars/spark-sql_2.11-1.4.1.jar target/scala-2.11/my-proj_2.11-1.0.jar` ,  added extra `/` for file protocol.

Comment: After several trails below command worked, file://root... is not able to read the location for the jar, please update the answer with the below syntax, Thanks a lot again!    command used: spark-submit --jars file:/root/Downloads/jars/spark-csv_2.10-1.0.3.jar,file:/root/Downloads/jars/commons-csv-1.2.jar,file:/root/Downloads/jars/spark-sql_2.11-1.4.1.jar  --class "SampleApp" --master local[2] target/scala-2.11/my-proj_2.11-1.0.jar

Answer (score 1):

Better solution is to use `--packages` option like below.

```
spark-submit --class "SampleApp" --master local[2] --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.5.0 target/scala-2.11/sample-project_2.11-1.0.jar
```

Make sure that `--packages` option precedes the application jar

Answer (score 0):

you have added spark-csv library to your sbt config - it means that you can compile your code with it,

but it still doesn't mean that it's present in runtime(spark sql and spark core are there by default)

so try to use --jars option of spark-submit to add spark-csv jar to runtime classpath or you can build fat-jar(not sure how you doing it with sbt)

Comment: He compiled it into his jar, so it should be there (note that he didn't use `provided`, which would indeed omit it)

Comment: @DanielZolnai, I might be wrong, but you need special plugin for this  sbt-assembly, sbt-proguard, sbt-onejar. By default with simple 'sbt package' 3'd party jars will not be assembled into jar.

Comment: You might be right, I assumed he was using assembly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution,  now I am getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat\
,any idea on this?

Comment: I have used: spark-submit --class "SampleApp" --master local[2] --jars file:/root/Downloads/jars/spark-csv_2.10-1.0.3.jar,/root/Downloads/jars/commons.csv-1.2.jar,/root/Downloads/jars/spark-sql_2.11-1.4.1.jar target/scala-2.11/my-proj_2.11-1.0.jar

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Spark 1.3 syntax of loading the CSV file into a dataframe.

If you check the [repository here](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv), you should use the following syntax on Spark 1.4 and higher:

```
val df = sqlContext.read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "true") // Use first line of all files as header
    .option("inferSchema", "true") // Automatically infer data types
    .load("cars.csv")
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggstion, I have changed the syntax!

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an option where in I could skip the --packages option and provide it directly in the assembly jar. The reason I faced this exception was 
*sqlContext.read.format("csv")* which meant it should know the data format of csv. Instead, to specify where the format csv is present use *sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")* so it knows where to look for it and does not throw an exception.