# ClassNotFoundException: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: csv.DefaultSource

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to create an assembly jar executable file But getting the following error

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: csv.DefaultSource`

The problem is with the CSV file read. The code is working fine in the IDE. Please help me

Scala code is below

```
package extendedtable

import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Row, SparkSession}
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

object mainObject {

 // var read = new fileRead
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder().appName("generationobj").master("local[*]").config("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled", value = true).getOrCreate()
    val sc: SparkContext = spark.sparkContext
    import spark.implicits._

    val atomData = spark.read.format("csv")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .load("Resources/atom.csv")

    val moleculeData = spark.read.format("csv")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .load("Resources/molecule.csv")

    val df = moleculeData.join(atomData,"molecule_id")
    val molecule_df = moleculeData
    val mid: List[Row] = molecule_df.select("molecule_id").collect.toList
    var listofmoleculeid: List[String] = mid.map(r => r.getString(0))
    // print(listofmoleculeid)
    newDF.createTempView("table")
    newDF.show()}
```

**Following is the build File**

```
name := "ExtendedTable"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.3.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.3.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "2.3.0"

mainClass := Some("extendedtable.mainObject")

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

Comment: Can you post build file ?? Make sure use same spark version

Comment: @Srinivas I have posted the build can you please look at that

Answer (score 6):

Change your `assemblyMergeStrategy` like below & then build jar file.

You need to include this `org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister` file inside your jar file & this file will be available inside `spark-sql` jar file.

Path is - `spark-sql_2.11-<version>.jar /META-INF/services/org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister`

This file contains below list

```
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JsonFileFormat
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.text.TextFileFormat
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ConsoleSinkProvider
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.TextSocketSourceProvider
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.RateSourceProvider
```

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF","services",xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.filterDistinctLines // Added this 
  case PathList("META-INF",xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard  
  case _ => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

Comment: I use `jar tvf` and could see this file in my jar, but this error still exists.

Comment: I had the same problem than OP and this solution solved the issue, I think it should be marked as accepted. Saved me a headache, thanks

Comment: Thank you! This was really helpful as I always assemble Spark Apps for a provided environment (local or cluster). But for the first time, I wanted to have everything in 1 Fat JAR self-contained and it was driving me crazy! Many thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Use `spark-submit` command to submit the spark job.

```
# Run application locally on 4 cores
./bin/spark-submit \
  --class extendedtable.mainObject \
  --master local[4] \
  /path/to/<your-jar>.jar
```

ref- [spark doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html)