# Running tensorflow with file on HDFS (cannot find libhdfs.so)

Tags: python, hadoop, tensorflow

I am running into an error "libhdfs.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory" (stack trace below) while trying to run a python script invoking a Tensorflow reader on a file stored in HDFS. I am running the script  on a node on the cluster which has Tensorflow in a virtualenv, activated at the time of execution. I set the following environment variables before execution:

- export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH
- export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
- export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/libhdfs.so
- export
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/amd64/server

I execute the script as such:

- CLASSPATH=$($LD_LIBRARY_PATH} classpath --glob) python TEST.py

This is the code in the script:

```
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([   
   "hdfs://hostname:port/user/hdfs/test.avro" ]) 
reader =
   tf.WholeFileReader() key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)

   with tf.Session() as sess:
       coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
       threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
       sess.run([key,value])
       coord.request_stop()
       coord.join(threads)
```

Below is the stack trace of the error. Any ideas on what is causing this error is appreciated (I have already checked that the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable has an explicit pointer to the libhdfs.so file prior to execution, unable to figure out why it still cannot find the file).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TEST.py", line 25, in <module>
    sess.run([key,value])
  File "/home/username/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 767, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/username/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 965, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/username/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1015, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/username/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1035, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: libhdfs.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
     [[Node: ReaderReadV2 = ReaderReadV2[_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](WholeFileReaderV2, input_producer)]]

Caused by op u'ReaderReadV2', defined at:
  File "TEST.py", line 19, in <module>
    key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)
  File "/home/username/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/io_ops.py", line 272, in read
    return gen_io_ops._reader_read_v2(self._reader_ref, queue_ref, name=name)
  File "/home/username/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_io_ops.py", line 410, in _reader_read_v2
    queue_handle=queue_handle, name=name)
  File "/home/username/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 763, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/username/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2395, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/username/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1264, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

NotFoundError (see above for traceback): libhdfs.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You should try `ldd` to see if the file is resolved. Since this is an install issue, please file an issue in our github page and CC @jhseu.

Comment: Instead of `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/libhdfs.so` can you try `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib` (i.e. adding the directory name instead of the filename)?

Comment: @mrry, this was a good idea. I tried it and now I'm getting the following error instead: "java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: hdfs". The only related issue I could find was at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17265002/hadoop-no-filesystem-for-scheme-file, which suggests a maven related issue. As far as I know, I'm not invoking maven when executing the script.

Comment: I think this means that your `CLASSPATH` doesn't include the correct JAR file for HDFS support. From your question, I can't figure out what the `CLASSPATH` expands to, but it's possible that it's missing some or all of the Hadoop JARs.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this issue the solution for me was copying this file to:

$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/lib/native

If you don't know the location of this file execute the following command to find it's location:

```
sudo updatedb
locate libhdfs.so
```

This will give you the location of the file. Next copy the file to $HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/lib/native:

```
cp locationOflibhdfs.so $HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/lib/native
```

Note: Replace locationOflibhdfs.so with the location of the libhdfs.so file.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
export CLASSPATH=$(${HADOOP_HDFS_HOME}/bin/hadoop classpath --glob)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**