# Apache Beam: Unable to find registrar for gs

Tags: java, maven, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Beam is using both Google's [auto/value](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/value) and [auto/service](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/service) tools.

I want to run a pipeline with Dataflow runner and data is stored on Google Cloud Storage.

I've added a dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
    <artifactId>beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
    <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-extensions-google-cloud-platform-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm able to start the pipeline from the IntelliJ. But when the jar is compiled through a `mvn package` and run with `java -jar` it throws an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find registrar for gs
```

The fatjar is package with `maven-assembly-plugin`. `GcsFileSystemRegistrar` class is in the jar.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue is in the way that you are building your fatjar. The `maven-assembly-plugin` is not handling files associated with `ServiceLoader` correctly. `ServiceLoader` relies on entries being listed within `META-INF/services/org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystemRegistrar` for each implementation so that Java knows how to find them.

The contents of the `META-INF/services/org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystemRegistrar` in your fatjar is likely only:

```
org.apache.beam.sdk.io.LocalFileSystemRegistrar
```

You need to have it list (and any other implementations that you want):

```
org.apache.beam.sdk.io.LocalFileSystemRegistrar
org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsFileSystemRegistrar
```

Your best bet is to use a tool which understands these `ServiceLoader` requirements like the `maven-shade-plugin` when configured to use the [ServicesResourceTransformer](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html#ServicesResourceTransformer) to build your fatjar.

Comment: Thanks! You're right. I've figure it out yesterday late at night by creating a Beam project from archetype and comparing the differences between mine `pom.xml` and the new `pom.xml`. After switching to `maven-shade-plugin` it started working just fine.

Comment: If you are using Gradle with the Shadow plugin, you can fix this by using `mergeServiceFiles()` in the `shadowJar { ... }` closure.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a problem with assembly strategy, you should accumulate/merge the services for `org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystemRegistrar`. More on similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17265002/hadoop-no-filesystem-for-scheme-file).