# Error executing SBT assembly

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jdbc, sbt

My problem is I am trying to execute a fatjar assembly generated with sbt, but I am not able to make it works.
When I run my code from the IDE (intelliJ) it works perfectly. However, once I generate the assembly with sbt, I am getting 2 different errors depending on the command I use to execute the jar:
**Executing the jar from java jvm:**

```
java -jar data-self-service-assembly-0.1.jar
```

After doing some stuff, I get this error on log:

```
[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@7435a578.
No FileSystem for scheme: hdfs
```

**Executing the jar from spark-submit:**

```
spark2-submit --master yarn --name self-service data-self-service-assembly-0.1.jar
```

After doing some stuff, I get this error on log:

```
[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@290c266c.
No suitable driver
```

I am running out on ideas, so any help that I can get to resolve my issue will be very appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/a/48860990/2250712 may help.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a stab at it

1 . Check if you have below snippet in your code

```
.setMaster("local[2]")
```

You can remove that

2 . Check the path of spark config .

```
spark-submit --verbose --master yarn-cluster  --files   --properties-file {spark_conf_file_location} --class {main_class}  {jar_location}
```

Comment: Thanks @Sandeep Das for your comment. I have tried with both of your recommendations and it doesn't work yet:_(

Answer (score 0):

finally I have been able to resolve the issue this way:

- I accessed the spark history server using this url: http://quickstart.cloudera:18089/
- I get the log of the execution to get more information about it
- I saw the classpath used by spark was this one: `Classpath","/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.2.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.12.0.p0.232957/lib/spark2/jars/`
- So I copied the jar files for jdbc in that path
- Then I submitted the job with this command: `spark2-submit --master yarn --name self-service data-self-service-assembly-0.1.jar`

The problem is that I didn't expect to have to make these actions, because I thought sbt would be able to assembly all the needed jars and recognize where they are later, but here there is some conflict between the classpath used by spark2-submit and sbt assembly.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It doesn’t. A Fat uber should have all as you say

Comment: Fat uber jar i meant