# java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: D while connecting from Windows with Oracle DB

Tags: apache-spark

I am using Apache Spark in my Windows machine and connected the oracle db using jdbc6.jar driver. When I try to print the schema using this command df.schema, am getting the result but when i try to show the result using command df.show i am getting this error

```
ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: D
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2660)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2667)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
```

Below are the codes which I used.

```
D:\Spark\spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7\bin>spark-shell --driver-class-path ojdbc6.jar --jars ojdbc6.jar --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.4.0

scala> sc.addJar("D:/Spark/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/ojdbc6.jar")

scala> val sqlContext=new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
```

**warning: there was one deprecation warning; re-run with -deprecation for details

```
sqlContext: org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext = org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext@42fc744**

scala> val df = sqlContext.load("jdbc",Map("url" -> "jdbc:oracle:thin:vision/vision123@10.16.1.101:1521:vision", "dbtable" -> "vision_business_day"))
```

**warning: there was one deprecation warning; re-run with -deprecation for details
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [COUNTRY: string, LE_BOOK: string ... 1 more field]**

```
scala> df.show
[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 1) / 1]19/08/02 11:44:46 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
        java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: D
                at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2660)
                at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2667)
                at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
                at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
                at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
                at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
                at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getHadoopFileSystem(Utils.scala:1866)
                at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.doFetchFile(Utils.scala:721)
                at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:509)
```

Comment: can you please add you code so that we can identify exactly where the problem exists.

Comment: can you please check similar problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17265002/hadoop-no-filesystem-for-scheme-file

Comment: I re-edited  and added the code