# How solve java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem in aws lambda?

Tags: java, hadoop, aws-lambda

After setup the [hadoop configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21118824/1251549) I got `java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem` even when `org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem` is present in the jar file .

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to "remove" `classloader` from `getClassByName` function. E.g. create `org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration` with `getClass` overrided method, like:

```
Configuration hadoopConfig = new Configuration() {
    public Class<?> getClassByName(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
      return Class.forName(name);
    }

};
```

**Notes**

1. This is just work implementation. Original implementation uses `Class.forName(name, true, classLoader);` so new overrided
   code may not work if so add `if` statement to change logic obly for `org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem`
2. The error happened and fixed only for AWS lambda. In other environments (like true Hadoop cluster) this may
   not be an appropriate solution