# Apache Flink Azure ABFS File Sink error (streaming) - UnsupportedFileSystemException: No FileSystem for scheme "file"

Tags: azure-blob-storage, apache-flink, flink-streaming, azure-data-lake

We use Apache Flink version 1.17.1 with Scala.
We are trying to write streaming data to ABFS file system.
The result is that files of 0 bytes are created. After that the error occurs.
[Image: files in azure container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nppwz.png)

Please see a simple example code in Scala.

```
object SimpleStream {

  val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment()

  env.enableCheckpointing(1000);
  env.getCheckpointConfig().setCheckpointStorage("abfss://<container-name>@<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net/testC/");

  def saveEvents() {

    import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
    val testEvents: DataStream[String] =
      env.fromCollection(List("a", "b", "c").asJava)

    val sink: FileSink[String] = FileSink
      .forRowFormat(
        new Path("abfss://<container-name>@<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net/output"),
        new SimpleStringEncoder[String]("UTF-8")
      )
      .withRollingPolicy(OnCheckpointRollingPolicy.build())
      .build()

    testEvents.sinkTo(sink)
    env.execute()
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    saveEvents()
  }
}
```

The code fails with the following exception:
`Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: No FileSystem for scheme "file"`

```
org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error: org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: Job failed (JobID: 366387423316a625a5d5eba7e9a6eb39)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:372)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:222)
        at org.apache.flink.client.ClientUtils.executeProgram(ClientUtils.java:105)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:851)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:245)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseAndRun(CliFrontend.java:1095)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$mainInternal$9(CliFrontend.java:1189)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.contexts.NoOpSecurityContext.runSecured(NoOpSecurityContext.java:28)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.mainInternal(CliFrontend.java:1189)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1157)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: Job failed (JobID: 366387423316a625a5d5eba7e9a6eb39)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:395)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1999)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.StreamContextEnvironment.getJobExecutionResult(StreamContextEnvironment.java:171)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.StreamContextEnvironment.execute(StreamContextEnvironment.java:122)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.execute(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:2058)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.execute(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:2036)
        at SimpleStream$.saveEvents(SimpleStream.scala:64)
        at SimpleStream$.main(SimpleStream.scala:68)
        at SimpleStream.main(SimpleStream.scala)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:355)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: Job failed (JobID: 366387423316a625a5d5eba7e9a6eb39)
        at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.ClusterClientJobClientAdapter.lambda$null$6(ClusterClientJobClientAdapter.java:130)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:642)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
        at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$retryOperationWithDelay$6(FutureUtils.java:302)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.rest.RestClusterClient.lambda$pollResourceAsync$32(RestClusterClient.java:787)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
        at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$retryOperationWithDelay$6(FutureUtils.java:302)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postFire(CompletableFuture.java:610)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:1085)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(CompletableFuture.java:478)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobResult.toJobExecutionResult(JobResult.java:144)
        at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.ClusterClientJobClientAdapter.lambda$null$6(ClusterClientJobClientAdapter.java:128)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Recovery is suppressed by NoRestartBackoffTimeStrategy
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.handleFailure(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:139)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.getFailureHandlingResult(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:83)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.recordTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:258)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.handleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:249)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.onTaskFailed(DefaultScheduler.java:242)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.onTaskExecutionStateUpdate(SchedulerBase.java:748)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerBase.java:725)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerNG.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerNG.java:80)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.updateTaskExecutionState(JobMaster.java:479)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.lambda$handleRpcInvocation$1(AkkaRpcActor.java:309)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.ClassLoadingUtils.runWithContextClassLoader(ClassLoadingUtils.java:83)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcInvocation(AkkaRpcActor.java:307)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:222)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.FencedAkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedAkkaRpcActor.java:84)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:168)
        at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:24)
        at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:20)
        at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:127)
        at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse$(PartialFunction.scala:126)
        at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:20)
        at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:175)
        at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:176)
        at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:176)
        at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:537)
        at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:535)
        at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:220)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:579)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:547)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:270)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:231)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:243)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: No FileSystem for scheme "file"
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:3443)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3466)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$300(FileSystem.java:174)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3574)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3521)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:540)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getLocal(FileSystem.java:496)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.confChanged(LocalDirAllocator.java:316)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:393)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:165)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:146)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.store.DataBlocks$DiskBlockFactory.createTmpFileForWrite(DataBlocks.java:980)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.store.DataBlocks$DiskBlockFactory.create(DataBlocks.java:960)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.services.AbfsOutputStream.createBlockIfNeeded(AbfsOutputStream.java:262)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.services.AbfsOutputStream.<init>(AbfsOutputStream.java:173)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystemStore.createFile(AzureBlobFileSystemStore.java:580)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystem.create(AzureBlobFileSystem.java:301)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1195)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1175)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1064)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1052)
        at org.apache.flink.fs.azurefs.AzureBlobFsRecoverableDataOutputStream.<init>(AzureBlobFsRecoverableDataOutputStream.java:63)
        at org.apache.flink.fs.azurefs.AzureBlobRecoverableWriter.getRecoverableFsDataOutputStream(AzureBlobRecoverableWriter.java:53)
        at org.apache.flink.fs.azure.common.hadoop.HadoopRecoverableWriter.open(HadoopRecoverableWriter.java:83)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.OutputStreamBasedPartFileWriter$OutputStreamBasedBucketWriter.openNewInProgressFile(OutputStreamBasedPartFileWriter.java:124)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.RowWiseBucketWriter.openNewInProgressFile(RowWiseBucketWriter.java:34)
        at org.apache.flink.connector.file.sink.writer.FileWriterBucket.rollPartFile(FileWriterBucket.java:261)
        at org.apache.flink.connector.file.sink.writer.FileWriterBucket.write(FileWriterBucket.java:188)
        at org.apache.flink.connector.file.sink.writer.FileWriter.write(FileWriter.java:198)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.operators.sink.SinkWriterOperator.processElement(SinkWriterOperator.java:158)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OneInputStreamTask$StreamTaskNetworkOutput.emitRecord(OneInputStreamTask.java:237)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.AbstractStreamTaskNetworkInput.processElement(AbstractStreamTaskNetworkInput.java:146)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.AbstractStreamTaskNetworkInput.emitNext(AbstractStreamTaskNetworkInput.java:110)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamOneInputProcessor.processInput(StreamOneInputProcessor.java:65)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.processInput(StreamTask.java:550)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.runMailboxLoop(MailboxProcessor.java:231)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.runMailboxLoop(StreamTask.java:839)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:788)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.runWithSystemExitMonitoring(Task.java:952)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.restoreAndInvoke(Task.java:931)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:745)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:562)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

We use the following Flink configuration for the storage account:

```
fs.azure.account.auth.type.<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net: SharedKey
fs.azure.account.key.<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net: ***
#
fs.azure.enable.flush: true
fs.azure.account.hns.enabled: true
#
fs.azure.createRemoteFileSystemDuringInitialization: true
fs.azure.always.use.https: true
```

Additionally, we have also put the flink-azure-fs-hadoop-1.17.1 library in the Flink plugins folder.

What are we missing in our setup?

The following Jira ticket suggests that ABFS should already work well with Flink File Sink.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-30128

We have also tried different options from the Hadoop docs but the error still persists.

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-azure/abfs.html

**Info added on 11th Oct**:

We have found out that the issue occurs in hadoop common library (version 3.3.4).
https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/branch-3.3.4/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.java

There are exactly the messages that we see in the log file.

```
2023-10-11 09:58:05,248 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem                              [] - Looking for FS supporting file
2023-10-11 09:58:05,248 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem                              [] - looking for configuration option fs.file.impl
2023-10-11 09:58:05,249 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem                              [] - Looking in service filesystems for implementation class
2023-10-11 09:58:05,249 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem                              [] - Creating FS file:///: duration 0:00.126s
2023-10-11 09:58:05,250 DEBUG org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask          [] - Cleanup StreamTask (operators closed: false, cancelled: false)
2023-10-11 09:58:05,254 WARN  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                    [] - Sink: Writer -> Sink: Committer (1/1)#0 (852db72b68b65307b97e33d7ca8e8b5a_20ba6b65f97481d5570070de90e4e791_0_0) switched from RUNNING to FAILED with failure cause:
org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: No FileSystem for scheme "file"
```

To resolve the error we have tried the following:

1. Adding the following configuration to flink-conf.yaml as well as in core-site.xml (below are settings as defined in flink-conf.yaml).

```
### Tried all 3 combinations of configuration separately

#These are names of variables and classes in older hadoop versions
flink.hadoop.fs.file.impl: org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem
flink.hadoop.fs.hdfs.impl: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem


#These are names of variables and classes in current hadoop (3.3.4)
flink.hadoop.fs.AbstractFileSystem.file.impl: org.apache.hadoop.fs.local.LocalFs
flink.hadoop.fs.AbstractFileSystem.hdfs.impl: org.apache.hadoop.fs.Hdfs

# If hadoop looks for the older variable names we should maybe point it to the current classes
flink.hadoop.fs.file.impl: org.apache.hadoop.fs.local.LocalFs
flink.hadoop.fs.hdfs.impl: org.apache.hadoop.fs.Hdfs
```

2. Adding a transformer in META-INFO in the hadoop shaded jar as described in:
   [hadoop No FileSystem for scheme: file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17265002/hadoop-no-filesystem-for-scheme-file/27532248#27532248)

**Environment details**:

4. Java: openjdk 11.0.20.1
5. Apache Flink: 1.17.1
6. Hadoop: 3.3.4

Comment: Looks like some path is not passed around. Check where the log that shows path is file:/// comes from and analyze where it should be configured.

Answer (score 0):

Do you put https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/flink/flink-shaded-hadoop-2-uber/2.8.3-10.0/flink-shaded-hadoop-2-uber-2.8.3-10.0.jar in the lib folder (or an older version thereof)?

UPDATED

Perhaps the problem is related to checkpointing (the FileSink only finalizes file writes during checkpointing). Do you have checkpointing enabled?

Also, it seems odd that the error says

> No FileSystem for scheme "file"

since it looks like you've used the scheme "abfss". Where have you used the "file" URI scheme?

Comment: Hi @David, thanks for your answer.
I have put the library in the lib folder.
Also, I have added dependencies in scala built.sbt file:

`libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-azure" % "3.3.1"`
`libraryDependencies += "org.apache.flink" % "flink-shaded-hadoop-2-uber" % "2.8.3-10.0"`

`libraryDependencies += "org.apache.flink" % "flink-azure-fs-hadoop" % "1.17.1" % "provided"`
```
Unfortunately the same error still persists.

Comment: Where exactly did you put the flink-azure-fs-hadoop-1.17.1 plugin library? Did you follow the instructions in https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/deployment/filesystems/plugins/#plugins ?

Comment: There's no need to add flink-shaded-hadoop-2-uber as a dependency. Flink will automatically load it if it is available.

Comment: We have put `flink-azure-fs-hadoop-1.17.1.jar` in this directory: `flink-1.17.1\plugins\azure-fs-hadoop\ ` .
Ok, thank you for for the information about the dependencies.

Comment: Ok, that looks right. Still not sure what's going wrong, but I've expanded my answer a bit.

Comment: I have added checkpointing to the code (pasted in the code from the question) but the error persists. We have also tried earlier to use checkpointing when inserting data to Kafka, but we had the same error ( `org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: No FileSystem for scheme "file"` ) and empty checkpoint folders were created in data lake container.  
<br/> 
We do not use "file" URI scheme. Currently we only test the ABFS connection with this small code snippet that is pasted the the question.